# Global teardown function in Jasmine.js

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I´m testing a Rails 4 / ember.js application with Jasmine.

How do I reset Ember after each spec without writing the teardown into every spec file?

```
# Spec/javascript/support/spec_helper.js.coffee

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter
App.setupForTesting()
App.injectTestHelpers()

# Reset Ember after each spec
# How do I tell jasmine to run a function after each spec?
# Metacode:
jasmine.afterEach ->
    App.reset()
```

Comment: question written in coffeescript for a javascript question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beforeEach`/`afterEach` can be declared globally as well, just use

```
beforeEach(function() {
  console.log('before');
});
```

or

```
afterEach(function() {
  console.log('after');
});
```

Here's an example of global implementation (not Ember).

http://jsbin.com/pavokiru/1/edit

Personally I would use qunit with Ember, they've built so many helpers for use with qunit, it'd be a lot of work to make it work with jasmine, especially when it comes to asynchronous processes (which are many in Ember).